# Convergence of difference of two CDFs

Tags: probability-theory

Let G and B be two random variables on $\mathbb{R}_+$ and $F_G$ and $F_B$ are their CDFs. They have the same expected value, $\mu$, and G second-order stochastically dominates B. Now, I want to evaluate the following term: 
\begin{align}
lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} [ x (F_G-F_B)]
\end{align} Is my intuition correct that the expression is equal to zero? As the expected value is finite, so is $\int_0^\infty x f_G(x) dx$. Therefore by integration by parts we have:
\begin{align}
E(G)=lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} [ x F_G] - \int_0^\infty F_G(x) dx
\end{align}
As $G$ and $B$ have the same expected value, we can rewrite
\begin{align}
lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} [ x (F_G-F_B)] = \mu+ \int_0^\infty F_G(x) dx - \mu - \int_0^\infty F_B(x) dx= \\
\int_0^\infty F_G(x) dx-\int_0^\infty F_B(x) dx
\end{align}
From now on I am stuck with the proof, as I can't manage to prove that the last two integrals are the same (if they are and my intuition is correct).

Is there anything wrong with this reasoning or am I doing it all wrong. Any help in this regard will be highly appreciated.

Comment: For every nonnegative integrable random variable $X$ with CDF $F$, $$\lim_{x\to\infty}x(1-F(x))=0$$ This is because $$x(1-F(x))=E(X_x)\qquad X_x=x\mathbf 1_{X>x}$$ Thus, $X_x\to0$ and $X_x\leqslant X$ hence Lebesgue dominated convergence theorem shows that $E(X_x)\to0$. Your result follows.